# WebGPU can't be enabled on Chrome v113

Tags: google-chrome, webgpu

## env

- Chrome: v113
- OS: Ubuntu 23.04
- Display: Nvidia RTX 3060 mobile

## error message

```
WebGPU has been disabled via blocklist or the command line.
Disabled Features: webgpu
```

## full text from chrome://gpu

```
Graphics Feature Status
Canvas: Hardware accelerated
Canvas out-of-process rasterization: Disabled
Direct Rendering Display Compositor: Disabled
Compositing: Hardware accelerated
Multiple Raster Threads: Enabled
OpenGL: Enabled
Rasterization: Hardware accelerated
Raw Draw: Disabled
Video Decode: Hardware accelerated
Video Encode: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Vulkan: Enabled
WebGL: Hardware accelerated
WebGL2: Hardware accelerated
WebGPU: Disabled
Driver Bug Workarounds
adjust_src_dst_region_for_blitframebuffer
clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
disable_discard_framebuffer
enable_webgl_timer_query_extensions
exit_on_context_lost
force_cube_complete
init_gl_position_in_vertex_shader
init_vertex_attributes
pack_parameters_workaround_with_pack_buffer
reset_base_mipmap_level_before_texstorage
unpack_alignment_workaround_with_unpack_buffer
unpack_overlapping_rows_separately_unpack_buffer
use_virtualized_gl_contexts
disabled_extension_GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced
disabled_extension_GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent
disabled_extension_GL_MESA_framebuffer_flip_y
Problems Detected
WebGPU has been disabled via blocklist or the command line.
Disabled Features: webgpu
Accelerated video encode has been disabled, either via blocklist, about:flags or the command line.
Disabled Features: video_encode
Program link fails in NVIDIA Linux if gl_Position is not set: 286468
Applied Workarounds: init_gl_position_in_vertex_shader
Clear uniforms before first program use on all platforms: 124764, 349137
Applied Workarounds: clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
Linux NVIDIA drivers don't have the correct defaults for vertex attributes: 351528
Applied Workarounds: init_vertex_attributes
MakeCurrent is slow on Linux with NVIDIA drivers: 449150, 514510
Applied Workarounds: use_virtualized_gl_contexts
NVIDIA fails glReadPixels from incomplete cube map texture: 518889
Applied Workarounds: force_cube_complete
Pack parameters work incorrectly with pack buffer bound: 563714
Applied Workarounds: pack_parameters_workaround_with_pack_buffer
Alignment works incorrectly with unpack buffer bound: 563714
Applied Workarounds: unpack_alignment_workaround_with_unpack_buffer
Framebuffer discarding can hurt performance on non-tilers: 570897
Applied Workarounds: disable_discard_framebuffer
Unpacking overlapping rows from unpack buffers is unstable on NVIDIA GL driver: 596774
Applied Workarounds: unpack_overlapping_rows_separately_unpack_buffer
Disable KHR_blend_equation_advanced until cc shaders are updated: 661715
Applied Workarounds: disable(GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced), disable(GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent)
Expose WebGL's disjoint_timer_query extensions on platforms with site isolation: 808744, 870491
Applied Workarounds: enable_webgl_timer_query_extensions
glTexStorage* are buggy when base mipmap level is not 0: 877874
Applied Workarounds: reset_base_mipmap_level_before_texstorage
Some drivers can't recover after OUT_OF_MEM and context lost: 893177
Applied Workarounds: exit_on_context_lost
adjust src/dst region if blitting pixels outside framebuffer on Linux NVIDIA: 830046
Applied Workarounds: adjust_src_dst_region_for_blitframebuffer
Disable GL_MESA_framebuffer_flip_y for desktop GL: 964010
Applied Workarounds: disable(GL_MESA_framebuffer_flip_y)
ANGLE Features
allowCompressedFormats (Frontend workarounds): Enabled: true
Allow compressed formats
cacheCompiledShader (Frontend features) anglebug:7036: Disabled
Enable to cache compiled shaders
disableAnisotropicFiltering (Frontend workarounds): Disabled
Disable support for anisotropic filtering
disableDrawBuffersIndexed (Frontend features) anglebug:7724: Disabled
Disable support for OES_draw_buffers_indexed and EXT_draw_buffers_indexed
disableProgramBinary (Frontend features) anglebug:5007: Disabled: IsPowerVrRogue(functions)
Disable support for GL_OES_get_program_binary
disableProgramCachingForTransformFeedback (Frontend workarounds): Disabled: IsAndroid() && isQualcomm
On some GPUs, program binaries don't contain transform feedback varyings
dumpShaderSource (Frontend features) anglebug:7760: Disabled
Write shader source to temp directory
emulatePixelLocalStorage (Frontend features) anglebug:7279: Enabled: true
Emulate ANGLE_shader_pixel_local_storage using shader images
enableCaptureLimits (Frontend features) anglebug:5750: Disabled
Set the context limits like frame capturing was enabled
enableProgramBinaryForCapture (Frontend features) anglebug:5658: Disabled
Even if FrameCapture is enabled, enable GL_OES_get_program_binary
enableShaderSubstitution (Frontend workarounds) anglebug:7761: Disabled
Check the filesystem for shaders to use instead of those provided through glShaderSource
forceDepthAttachmentInitOnClear (Frontend workarounds) anglebug:7246: Disabled
Force depth attachment initialization on clear ops
forceGlErrorChecking (Frontend features) https://issuetracker.google.com/220069903: Disabled
Force GL error checking (i.e. prevent applications from disabling error checking
forceInitShaderVariables (Frontend features): Disabled
Force-enable shader variable initialization
forceRobustResourceInit (Frontend features) anglebug:6041: Disabled
Force-enable robust resource init
loseContextOnOutOfMemory (Frontend workarounds): Enabled: true
Some users rely on a lost context notification if a GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY error occurs
scalarizeVecAndMatConstructorArgs (Frontend workarounds) 1165751: Disabled: false
Always rewrite vec/mat constructors to be consistent
singleThreadedTextureDecompression (Frontend workarounds): Disabled
Disables multi-threaded decompression of compressed texture formats
RGBA4IsNotSupportedForColorRendering (OpenGL workarounds): Disabled: functions->standard == STANDARD_GL_DESKTOP && isIntel
GL_RGBA4 is not color renderable
RGBDXT1TexturesSampleZeroAlpha (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:3729: Disabled: IsApple()
Sampling BLACK texels from RGB DXT1 textures returns transparent black on Mac.
addAndTrueToLoopCondition (OpenGL workarounds): Disabled: IsApple() && isIntel
Calculation of loop conditions in for and while loop has bug
adjustSrcDstRegionForBlitFramebuffer (OpenGL workarounds) 830046: Enabled: IsLinux() || (IsAndroid() && isNvidia) || (IsWindows() && isNvidia) || (IsApple() && functions->standard == STANDARD_GL_ES)
Many platforms have issues with blitFramebuffer when the parameters are large.
allowAstcFormats (OpenGL workarounds): Enabled: !isMesa || isIntel && (Is9thGenIntel(device) || IsGeminiLake(device) || IsCoffeeLake(device) || Is11thGenIntel(device) || Is12thGenIntel(device))
Enable ASTC on desktop OpenGL
allowClearForRobustResourceInit (OpenGL workarounds) 848952: Disabled: IsApple()
Using glClear for robust resource initialization is buggy on some drivers and leads to texture corruption. Default to data uploads except on MacOS where it is very slow.
allowETCFormats (OpenGL workarounds): Disabled: isIntel && !IsSandyBridge(device) && !IsIvyBridge(device) && !IsHaswell(device)
Enable ETC2/EAC on desktop OpenGL
alwaysCallUseProgramAfterLink (OpenGL workarounds) 110263: Enabled: true
Always call useProgram after a successful link to avoid a driver bug
alwaysUnbindFramebufferTexture2D (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:5536: Enabled: isNvidia && (IsWindows() || IsLinux())
Force unbind framebufferTexture2D before binding renderbuffer to work around driver bug.
avoid1BitAlphaTextureFormats (OpenGL workarounds): Disabled: functions->standard == STANDARD_GL_DESKTOP && isAMD
Issue with 1-bit alpha framebuffer formats
bindFramebufferForTimerQueries (OpenGL workarounds) 1356053: Disabled: IsMali(functions)
Some drivers require a non-zero framebuffer when beginQuery for TimeElapsed orTimestampis called.
bindTransformFeedbackBufferBeforeBindBufferRange (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:5140: Disabled: IsApple()
Bind transform feedback buffers to the generic binding point before calling glBindBufferBase or glBindBufferRange.
clampArrayAccess (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:2978: Disabled: IsAndroid() || isAMD || !functions->hasExtension("GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior")
Clamp uniform array access to avoid reading invalid memory.
clampFragDepth (OpenGL workarounds): Enabled: isNvidia
gl_FragDepth is not clamped correctly when rendering to a floating point depth buffer
clampMscRate (OpenGL workarounds) 1042393: Disabled: IsLinux() && IsWayland()
Some drivers return bogus values for GetMscRate, so we clamp it to 30Hz
clampPointSize (OpenGL workarounds): Enabled: IsAndroid() || isNvidia
The point size range reported from the API is inconsistent with the actual behavior
clearToZeroOrOneBroken (OpenGL workarounds) 710443: Disabled: IsApple() && isIntel && GetMacOSVersion() < OSVersion(10, 12, 6)
Clears when the clear color is all zeros or ones do not work.
clipSrcRegionForBlitFramebuffer (OpenGL workarounds) 830046: Disabled: IsApple() || (IsLinux() && isAMD)
Issues with blitFramebuffer when the parameters don't match the framebuffer size.
decodeEncodeSRGBForGenerateMipmap (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:4646: Disabled: IsApple()
Decode and encode before generateMipmap for srgb format textures.
disableBlendFuncExtended (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:1085: Disabled: (IsAndroid() && isQualcomm) || (IsApple() && isIntel && GetMacOSVersion() < OSVersion(10, 14, 0))
ARB_blend_func_extended does not pass the tests
disableDrawBuffersIndexed (OpenGL workarounds): Disabled: IsWindows() && isAMD
Disable OES_draw_buffers_indexed extension.
disableGPUSwitchingSupport (OpenGL workarounds) 1091824: Disabled: isDualGPUMacWithNVIDIA
Disable GPU switching support (use only the low-power GPU) on older MacBook Pros.
disableMultisampledRenderToTexture (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:2894: Disabled: isAdreno4xxOnAndroidLessThan51 || isAdreno4xxOnAndroid70 || isAdreno5xxOnAndroidLessThan70 || isAdreno5xxOnAndroid71 || isLinuxVivante || IsAndroid()
Many drivers have bugs when using GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture
disableNativeParallelCompile (OpenGL workarounds) 1094869: Disabled: isTSANBuild && IsLinux() && isNvidia
Do not use native KHR_parallel_shader_compile even when available.
disableSemaphoreFd (OpenGL workarounds) 1046462: Disabled: IsLinux() && isAMD && isMesa && mesaVersion < (std::array<int, 3>{19, 3, 5})
Disable GL_EXT_semaphore_fd extension
disableSyncControlSupport (OpenGL workarounds) 1137851: Disabled: IsLinux() && isIntel && isMesa && mesaVersion[0] == 20
Speculative fix for issues on Linux/Wayland where exposing GLX_OML_sync_control renders Chrome unusable
disableTextureClampToBorder (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:7405: Disabled: isImagination
Imagination devices generate INVALID_ENUM when setting the texture border color.
disableTimestampQueries (OpenGL workarounds) 811661: Disabled: (IsLinux() && isVMWare) || (IsAndroid() && isNvidia) || (IsAndroid() && GetAndroidSdkLevel() < 27 && IsAdreno5xxOrOlder(functions)) || (!isMesa && IsMaliT8xxOrOlder(functions)) || (!isMesa && IsMaliG31OrOlder(functions))
Disable GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query extension
disableWorkerContexts (OpenGL workarounds) 849576: Enabled: (IsWindows() && (isIntel || isAMD)) || (IsLinux() && isNvidia) || IsIOS() || IsAndroid() || IsAndroidEmulator(functions)
Some tests have been seen to fail using worker contexts
doWhileGLSLCausesGPUHang (OpenGL workarounds) 644669: Disabled: IsApple() && functions->standard == STANDARD_GL_DESKTOP && GetMacOSVersion() < OSVersion(10, 11, 0)
Some GLSL constructs involving do-while loops cause GPU hangs
doesSRGBClearsOnLinearFramebufferAttachments (OpenGL workarounds): Disabled: isIntel || isAMD
Issue clearing framebuffers with linear attachments when GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB is enabled
dontInitializeUninitializedLocals (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:2046: Disabled: IsAndroid() && isQualcomm
Initializing uninitialized locals caused odd behavior in a few WebGL 2 tests
dontRelinkProgramsInParallel (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:3045: Disabled: IsAndroid() || (IsWindows() && isIntel)
Relinking a program in parallel is buggy
dontUseLoopsToInitializeVariables (OpenGL workarounds) 809422: Disabled: (IsAndroid() && isQualcomm) || (isIntel && IsApple())
For loops used to initialize variables hit native GLSL compiler bugs
emulateAbsIntFunction (OpenGL workarounds) 642227: Disabled: IsApple() && isIntel
abs(i) where i is an integer returns unexpected result
emulateAtan2Float (OpenGL workarounds) 672380: Enabled: isNvidia
atan(y, x) may return a wrong answer
emulateClipDistanceState (OpenGL workarounds): Disabled: isQualcomm
Some drivers ignore GL_CLIP_DISTANCEi_EXT state.
emulateCopyTexImage2D (OpenGL workarounds): Disabled: isApple
Replace CopyTexImage2D with TexImage2D + CopyTexSubImage2D.
emulateCopyTexImage2DFromRenderbuffers (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:4674: Disabled: IsApple() && functions->standard == STANDARD_GL_ES && !(isAMD && IsWindows())
CopyTexImage2D spuriously returns errors on iOS when copying from renderbuffers.
emulateImmutableCompressedTexture3D (OpenGL workarounds) 1060012: Disabled: isQualcomm
Use non-immutable texture allocation to work around a driver bug.
emulateIsnanFloat (OpenGL workarounds) 650547: Disabled: isIntel && IsApple() && IsSkylake(device) && GetMacOSVersion() < OSVersion(10, 13, 2)
Using isnan() on highp float will get wrong answer
emulateMaxVertexAttribStride (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:1936: Disabled: IsLinux() && functions->standard == STANDARD_GL_DESKTOP && isAMD
Some drivers return 0 when MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIB_STRIED queried
emulatePackSkipRowsAndPackSkipPixels (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:4849: Disabled: IsApple()
GL_PACK_SKIP_ROWS and GL_PACK_SKIP_PIXELS are ignored in Apple's OpenGL driver.
emulatePrimitiveRestartFixedIndex (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:3997: Disabled: functions->standard == STANDARD_GL_DESKTOP && functions->isAtLeastGL(gl::Version(3, 1)) && !functions->isAtLeastGL(gl::Version(4, 3))
When GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART_FIXED_INDEX is not available, emulate it with GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART and glPrimitiveRestartIndex.
emulateRGB10 (OpenGL workarounds) 1300575: Enabled: functions->standard == STANDARD_GL_DESKTOP
Emulate RGB10 support using RGB10_A2.
finishDoesNotCauseQueriesToBeAvailable (OpenGL workarounds): Enabled: functions->standard == STANDARD_GL_DESKTOP && isNvidia
glFinish doesn't cause all queries to report available result
flushBeforeDeleteTextureIfCopiedTo (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:4267: Disabled: IsApple() && isIntel
Some drivers track CopyTex{Sub}Image texture dependencies incorrectly. Flush before glDeleteTextures in this case
flushOnFramebufferChange (OpenGL workarounds) 1181068: Disabled: IsApple() && Has9thGenIntelGPU(systemInfo)
Switching framebuffers without a flush can lead to crashes on Intel 9th Generation GPU Macs.
initFragmentOutputVariables (OpenGL workarounds) 1171371: Disabled: IsAdreno42xOr3xx(functions)
No init gl_FragColor causes context lost
initializeCurrentVertexAttributes (OpenGL workarounds): Enabled: isNvidia
During initialization, assign the current vertex attributes to the spec-mandated defaults
keepBufferShadowCopy (OpenGL workarounds): Disabled: !CanMapBufferForRead(functions)
Maintain a shadow copy of buffer data when the GL API does not permit reading data back.
limitMax3dArrayTextureSizeTo1024 (OpenGL workarounds) 927470: Disabled: limitMaxTextureSize
Limit max 3d texture size and max array texture layers to 1024 to avoid system hang
limitMaxMSAASamplesTo4 (OpenGL workarounds) 797243: Disabled: IsAndroid() || (IsApple() && (isIntel || isAMD || isNvidia))
Various rendering bugs have been observed when using higher MSAA counts
limitWebglMaxTextureSizeTo4096 (OpenGL workarounds) 927470: Disabled: IsAndroid() || limitMaxTextureSize
Limit webgl max texture size to 4096 to avoid frequent out-of-memory errors
packLastRowSeparatelyForPaddingInclusion (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:1512: Enabled: IsApple() || isNvidia
When uploading textures from an pack buffer, some drivers count an extra row padding
packOverlappingRowsSeparatelyPackBuffer (OpenGL workarounds): Enabled: isNvidia
In the case of packing to a pixel pack buffer, pack overlapping rows row by row
passHighpToPackUnormSnormBuiltins (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:7527: Disabled: isQualcomm
packUnorm4x8 fails on Pixel 4 if it is not passed a highp vec4.
preAddTexelFetchOffsets (OpenGL workarounds) 642605: Disabled: IsApple() && isIntel
Intel Mac drivers mistakenly consider the parameter position of nagative vaule as invalid even if the sum of position and offset is in range, so we need to add workarounds by rewriting texelFetchOffset(sampler, position, lod, offset) into texelFetch(sampler, position + offset, lod).
promotePackedFormatsTo8BitPerChannel (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:5469: Disabled: IsApple() && hasAMD
Packed color formats are buggy on Macs with AMD GPUs
queryCounterBitsGeneratesErrors (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:3027: Disabled: IsNexus5X(vendor, device)
Drivers generate errors when querying the number of bits in timer queries
readPixelsUsingImplementationColorReadFormatForNorm16 (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:4214: Disabled: !isIntel && functions->standard == STANDARD_GL_ES && functions->isAtLeastGLES(gl::Version(3, 1)) && functions->hasGLESExtension("GL_EXT_texture_norm16")
Quite some OpenGL ES drivers don't implement readPixels for RGBA/UNSIGNED_SHORT from EXT_texture_norm16 correctly
reapplyUBOBindingsAfterUsingBinaryProgram (OpenGL workarounds) anglebug:1637: Disabled: isAMD || IsAndroid()
Some drivers forget about UBO bindings when using program binaries
regenerateStructNames (OpenGL workarounds) 403957: Disabled: IsApple()
All Mac drivers do not handle struct scopes correctly. This workaround overwrites a structname with a unique prefix.
removeDynamicIndexingOfSwizzledVector (OpenGL workarounds) 709351: Disabled: IsApple() || IsAndroid() || IsWindows()
Dynamic indexing of swizzled l-values doesn't work correctly on various platforms.
removeInvariantAndCentroidForESSL3 (OpenGL workarounds): Disabled: functions->isAtMostGL(gl::Version(4, 1)) || (functions->standard == STANDARD_GL_DESKTOP && isAMD)
Fix spec difference between GLSL 4.1 or lower and ESSL3
resetTexImage2DBaseLevel (OpenGL workarounds) 705865: Disabled: IsApple() && isIntel && GetMacOSVersion() >= OSVersion(10, 12, 4)
Reset texture base level before calling glTexImage2D to work around pixel comparison failure.
rewriteFloatUnaryMinusOperator (OpenGL workarounds) 308366: Disabled: IsApple() && isIntel && GetMacOSVersion() < OSVersion(10, 12, 0)
Using '-<float>' will get wrong answer
rewriteRepeatedAssignToSwizzled (OpenGL workarounds): Enabled: isNvidia
Repeated assignment to swizzled values inside a GLSL user-defined function have incorrect results
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

according to [https://developer.chrome.com/blog/webgpu-release/](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/webgpu-release/#:%7E:text=This%20initial%20release%20of%20WebGPU%20is%20available%20on%20ChromeOS%2C%20macOS%2C%20and%20Windows.%20Support%20for%20other%20platforms%20is%20coming%20later%20this%20year.)

> This initial release of WebGPU is available on **ChromeOS**, **macOS**, and **Windows**. Support for other platforms is coming later this year.

Answer (score 4):

WebGpu works for me on linux debian 12 in June 2023 with `google-chrome-beta --enable-unsafe-webgpu`.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I note the warning: "You are using an unsupported command-line flag... Stability and security will suffer."

Answer (score 0):

Use this line could enable WebGPU:
`google-chrome-stable --enable-unsafe-webgpu --enable-features=Vulkan`

Isn't WebGPU enabled by default on Chrome v113?